# Laravel 6 pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, import-from-excel

This is where i get the error:

`$data = Excel::import($path, function($reader) {})->get();`

I changed the `load()` to `import()`. I want to run this code in Laravel 6, but version 3 of MaatWebsiteExcel does not support `load()`.
I've been searching for solutions, yet i cant find any....

This is my controller:

````
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Contact;
use App\CsvData;
use App\Http\Requests\CsvImportRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Session;
use DB;

class ImportController extends Controller
{

    public function getImport()
    {
        return view('import');
    }

     function parseImport(CsvImportRequest $request)
    {

        $path = $request->file('csv_file')->getRealPath();

        if ($request->has('header')) {
            $data = Excel::import($path, function($reader) {})->get();
        } else {
            $data = array_map('str_getcsv', file($path));
        }

        if (count($data) > 0) {
            if ($request->has('header')) {
                $csv_header_fields = [];
                foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {
                    $csv_header_fields[] = $key;
                }
            }
            $csv_data = array_slice($data, 0, 2);

            $credentials = $request->file('csv_file')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename = CsvData::all('csv_filename');


            if(CsvData::where('csv_filename', '=' ,$credentials)->exists()){

            return redirect()->back()->with('alert', 'This specific file has already been imported!');

            }
            else{
             $csv_data_file = CsvData::create([
                'csv_filename' => $request->file('csv_file')->getClientOriginalName(),
                'csv_header' => $request->has('header'),
                'csv_data' => json_encode($data)
                ]);

            }

        }
         else {
            return redirect()->back();
        }

        return view('import_fields', compact( 'csv_header_fields', 'csv_data', 'csv_data_file'));

    }

    public function processImport(Request $request)
    {
        $data = CsvData::find($request->csv_data_file_id);
        $csv_data = json_decode($data->csv_data, true);

        if(CsvData::where('csv_data', '=' ,$csv_data)->exists()){
        return redirect()->back()->with('alert', 'This file has already been imported!');
    }
        else{

            foreach ($csv_data as $row) {
            $contact = new Contact();

            foreach (config('app.db_fields') as $index => $field) {
                if ($data->csv_header) {
                    $contact->$field = $row[$request->fields[$field]];
                } else {
                    $contact->$field = $row[$request->fields[$index]];
                }

            }
foreach($contact as $contacts){
        $contact->posted_by             = $contacts->posted_by;
        $contact->employer              = $contacts->employer;
        $contact->address               = $contacts->address;
        $contact->barangay              = $contacts->barangay;
        $contact->citymunicipality      = $contacts->citymunicipality;
        $contact->province              = $contacts->province;
        $contact->region                = $contacts->region;
        $contact->position              = $contacts->position;
        $contact->job_description       = $contacts->job_description;
        $contact->salary                = $contacts->salary;
        $contact->count                 = $contacts->count;
        $contact->work_location         = $contacts->work_location;
        $contact->nature_of_work        = $contacts->nature_of_work;
        $contact->min_work_exp_mos      = $contacts->min_work_exp_mos;
        $contact->min_educ_level        = $contacts->min_educ_level;
        $contact->coursemajor           = $contacts->coursemajor;
        $contact->min_age               = $contacts->min_age;
        $contact->max_age               = $contacts->max_age;
        $contact->min_height            = $contacts->min_height;
        $contact->sex                   = $contacts->sex;
        $contact->civil_status          = $contacts->civil_status;
        $contact->other_qualifications  = $contacts->other_qualifications;
        $contact->remarks               = $contacts->remarks;
        $contact->accept_disability     = $contacts->accept_disability;
        $contact->date_posted           = $contacts->date_posted['date'];
        $contact->valid_until           = $contacts->valid_until['date'];
        $contact->date_created          = $contacts->date_created['date'];
        $contact->last_modified_by      = $contacts->last_modified_by['date'];
        $contact->date_last_modified    = $contacts->date_last_modified['date'];

    }
    $contact->save();
        return view('import_success');


    }
     }
}
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of the `import()` method is not the path to the file anymore in `Laravel 3.1`, but the class name of the `Import` file you have to create. 
You need to follow below steps to use `import` method

**Step1:** Create Import File using below command.

```
php artisan make:import CsvImport
```

**Step2:**  Inside CsvImport make changes like this:

```
namespace App\Imports;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class CsvImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        return $rows; //add this line
    }
}
```

**Step3:** In Controller make changes like this:

```
 $path = $request->file('csv_file')->getRealPath();
 $rows = Excel::import(new CsvImport, $path);
```

Reference:

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/basics.html

Comment: I tried that and it led me to another error
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Too few arguments to function Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::import(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\BarangayInformationDesk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 261 and at least 2 expected

Comment: Thank you, the code you gave worked and the import issue is resolved. There are still few problems but ill find a way solving these. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I need only those columns after specific indexing, which I consider practically the same use case as described in the question at the top of this page. I propose the following as solution.

`$fileArr = (new BulkSampleImport)->toArray($request->file);`

Comment: I edited to turn this into an obvious answer, assuming that the author tried to answer (otherwise it would be flaggable as "not an answer") and should be deleted.