# Error in Data Import from Excel in Laravel 6?

Tags: excel, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I am getting error when i am Importing data from Excel Sheet, I am doing it by Controller. and I am getting this error `Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::load()`

Please let me know if it can be possible by Model,....

Here are my Model Lead.php

```
<?php
  namespace App;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  class Lead extends Model
 {
 protected $primaryKey = 'lId';
}
```

Here are my Controller LeadController.php

```
public function import(Request $request){
$this->validate($request, [
    'select_file' => 'required|mimes:xls, xlsx'
]);
$path=$request->file('select_file')->getRealPath();
$data=Excel::load($path)->get();
if($data->count() > 0)
{
    foreach ($data->toArray() as $key => $value) 
    {
        foreach($valuse as $row)
        {
            $insert_data[]=array(
                'Name'=>$row['name'],
                'Project'=>$row['project'],
                'Follow up Date'=>$row['followup'],
                'Lead Source'=>$row['lead_source'],
                'Email Id'=>$row['email'],
                'Message'=>$row['message'],
                'Phone Number'=>$row['number'],
                'Status'=>$row['status'],
            );
        }
    }
    if(!empty($insert_data))
    {
        DB::table('leads')->insert($insert_data);
    } 
}
return back()->with('success', 'Excel Data Imported successfully.');
}
```

And here are my View code...

```
<form action="{{ route('import') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf
                            <input type="file" name="select_file" class="form-control">
                            <br>
                            <input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Here are my Web.php

```
Route::post('lead/import', 'LeadController@import')->name('import');
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473098/call-to-undefined-method-maatwebsite-excel-excelload

Answer (score 0):

As per [Laravel Excel 3 documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/upgrade.html#upgrading-to-3-from-2-1) changes

> `Excel::load()` is removed and replaced by `Excel::import($yourImport)`

So resolve this error
Either use version `2.x` as below

```
composer require "maatwebsite/excel:~2.1.0"
```

**OR**

Use `import()` method of `version 3`

You need to follow below steps to use `import` method of `version3`

**Step1:** Create Import File using below command.

```
php artisan make:import CsvImport
```

**Step2:**  Inside CsvImport make changes like this:

```
namespace App\Imports;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class CsvImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        return $rows; //add this line
    }
}
```

**Step3:** In Controller make changes like this:

```
 $path = $request->file('csv_file')->getRealPath();
 $rows = Excel::import(new CsvImport, $path);
```

Comment: I am getting this error after using `import()`...`Too few arguments to function Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::import(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\group3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 261 and at least 2 expected`

Comment: @sainitor You can follow this tutorial to make it work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60612874/laravel-6-pathinfo-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given/60613451#60613451

Answer (score 0):

I done the import function before and meet this error also.
You can either use version 2.x which mentioned by Sehdev :

1. delete the config/excel.php
2. in your composer.json, change "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1" to "maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1"
3. run `composer update`

Or if you insist to use it in version 3.1 like me, this is how I solve it.
Use :

```
$data = Excel::toArray(new ContactImport,$request->file('select_file'))[0];
```

Instead of :

```
$data=Excel::load($path)->get();
```

`ContactImport` is the import class I created via `PHP artisan make: import ContactImport --model=User` by following the **5 minutes quick start** in Laravel Excel documentation.

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/

I am a Laravel newbie. Hope my suggestion can solve your problem.